# Как сменить цвет только части текста в TextView

Tags: java, android, строки

Есть текст в `TextView`, сам текст прописан через `String`.

Можно ли как-то сменить цвет только части текста, а не всего полностью ?

Comment: Добавьте теги языка программирования/используемой платформы. Непонятно, что за `textViev`.

Comment: textViev - окно вывода текста в android studio. теги смены текста не срабатывают.

Comment: Android Studio - просто инструмент для написания кода и никакого "окна" вывода текста в ней самой нет. Это "окно" в Android (такая ОС, на которой будет выполняться программа, написанная в Android Studio)

Comment: Тот же вопрос 6 летней давности на англо-саксонском [how can I change color part of a TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4032676/3212712). Находится на первой строке выдачи гугла на запрос `android textview color part of text`

Comment: Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как правильный

Answer (score 3):

```
String s = "Hello Everyone";
SpannableString ss =  new SpannableString(s);
ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // устанавливаем цвет слову Hello

TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.setText(ss);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Источник: http://java-help.ru/textview-multifont/